# Can't explain some entries in output of the 'last' command

Tags: ubuntu

Here is some entries in the terminal output of the 'last'

```
alex     tty2         tty2             Sun May 29 14:34 - down  (20+15:14)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-44-generi Sun May 29 14:34 - 05:48 (20+15:14)
alex     tty2         tty2             Sun Mar 27 11:54 - down  (63+02:38)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-35-generi Sun Mar 27 10:29 - 14:33 (63+04:03)
alex     tty2         tty2             Sat Mar 12 19:21 - crash (14+14:08)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-35-generi Sat Mar 12 19:20 - 14:33 (77+18:12)
alex     tty2         tty2             Wed Feb 23 08:34 - crash (17+10:46)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-30-generi Mon Jan 10 05:07 - 14:33 (139+08:25)
alex     tty2         tty2             Sun Feb 20 15:42 - crash (-41+10:34)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-28-generi Sun Feb 20 15:42 - 14:33 (97+21:51)
alex     tty2         tty2             Sun Feb 20 15:36 - crash  (00:05)
```

What scenarios can you suggest other than aliens if:

- This is not my computer, but I have it now, and line

  ```
  reboot   system boot  5.13.0-35-generi Sat Mar 12 19:20 - 14:33 (77+18:12)
  ```

is the date and time when I opened the laptop lid for the first time, I had a password, since I am a relative of the owner of the computer.
Please pay attention to line

reboot   system boot  5.13.0-30-generi Mon Jan 10 05:07 - 14:33 (139+08:25)

where there is a strange date. Mainly I'm interested in how such a record with such a date could appear (except for aliens). How can the absence of an authorized login be explained by this strange date? After all, always after the "reboot"- user , the next line is the authorized login. Or am I missing something? Any other scenarios are acceptable, both with the participation of the owner of the computer, and with the participation of a neighbor while the owner was sleeping. Let me remind you that I am not the owner of the computer, but the interested party- relative of the owner. ps
Both batteries (main and BIOS) are normal, the only OS installed on the computer is Ubuntu.
Any opinions are welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The dates would all seem to fit the calendar of year 2022.

The `(dd+hh:mm)` values would be the length of the respective login session, or the time from a reboot to the previous one. It looks like the laptop was infrequently used, and perhaps was put away in suspended-to-RAM mode, until the battery was exhausted by self-discharge, causing a loss of the suspended state. A recovery from such a state would have closed off any previous logins with a `crash` entry.

Any system startup will normally generate a `reboot` entry. If the system is shut down normally in a controlled fashion, the previous `reboot` entry is closed down with a `down (uptime)` at the actual shutdown time. If the system starts up without a previous controlled shutdown, the previous `reboot` entry will be assumed to have crashed just before the current system startup time (because the logic was originally developed for servers, which were assumed to be running all the time).

```
alex     tty2         tty2             Wed Feb 23 08:34 - crash (17+10:46)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-30-generi Mon Jan 10 05:07 - 14:33 (139+08:25)
alex     tty2         tty2             Sun Feb 20 15:42 - crash (-41+10:34)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-28-generi Sun Feb 20 15:42 - 14:33 (97+21:51)
alex     tty2         tty2             Sun Feb 20 15:36 - crash  (00:05)
```

This looks like the system time may have been modified sometime at or after Sun Feb 20, causing a reboot entry with an approximated uptime of "97 days and almost 22 hours", then a login session time of "negative 41 days" for user `alex`. Note that the difference between "Jan 10" and Feb 20 is about 41 days. The "crash" entries suggest the system was not properly shut down, but may have had the power forced off (or just suspended until battery exhaustion).

However, because modern OSs tend to try and sync their time from the internet whenever possible, it looks like while the system was booted once at "Jan 10" (which is possibly a bogus time), by the time the user `alex` logged in, the time of 23 Feb was already resynced.

If the time range between Jan 10 of 2022 and Feb 24 of 2022 has some legal importance (e.g. the laptop allegedly contains the latest version of a deceased person's last will and testament, dated within that range), then I would suggest a proper forensic examination of the system by a trusted impartial expert, instead of asking around on the internet.

Comment: Legal issues have nothing to do with it, so let me be a little more curious? )
Small clarification. According to the journal log, kernel 5.13.0-30 was loaded on 22 feb. at 06:25-06:53, which means the time was changed after that. But this is not important in this situation. I'm curious how it happened that the "reboot"-user am 10 jan. is there in the terminal record, but there was no authorized  login? Can  change the time before login entering ?

Comment: In most PCs, you can use BIOS settings to change system time before the OS is even started. The `reboot` record is created as part of the normal Linux system start-up process, and does not refer to an actual user account. I could imagine someone using BIOS settings to turn the clock backwards (for whatever reason), and then finding out that automatic time synchronization will reset the system clock back to the correct time practically as soon as a network connection is established; in this case, before they even had time to log in.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot that a computer can connect to the network even without an authorized login). But this is one of the likely scenarios, that the reboot took place on February 23rd? We can’t set the exact date and time when a computer started with the wrong date/time, can we? Just in case, this incorrect date is earlier than the beginning of the history of this OS on this computer, the countdown of the history  began around the beginning of February.

Comment: I want to understand, if we assume that the reboot was on February 22, after 06:53 (which I wrote about above), then how likely is it for the computer to work for a day with an unclear status? Naturally, taking into account records from the terminal. And what kind of regime and status could this be?

Comment: Remember that the `last` does not record the times the system was suspended and then resumed. Given that the kernel 5.13.0-30 was installed on Feb 22, that indeed further restricts the time range during which the time manipulation happened. If the system was in a place where there is a previously-used WiFi network, or it had a network cable connected, it would sync time from internet as soon as the network connection came up after boot. Whoever manipulated the time would probably attempted to login immediately afterwards, so I'd guess the manipulation to have happened just before Feb 23 08:34.

Comment: So you rule out such a scenario?
Time manipulation February 22, before or during boot, disable time synchronization, mount partition in "ro" mode, then enter. Thus, the login will be displayed and there will be no authorization on January 10th. The laptop works for a day (hopefully in full-function mode?), then somehow (how?) exits this mode and normal authorization occurs on February 23. Is this option possible?

Comment: Assuming the perpetrator is a basic home user with no command line skills, that seems not likely. With the root partition in read-only mode, I'd expect an X11 session to crash immediately because writing the session cookie file to disk will not be possible. Not sure about Wayland; not very useful in RO anyway. A command line maven could do quite a lot of things, including covering the tracks of any date manipulation better than this. Someone who knows how to use a small screwdriver could have removed the disk and plugged it to another computer to access it without leaving any logs at all.